# Get a SCSS custom property value using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have an element with that have a SCSS custom property with a certain value.
and if this value matches a certain regex pattern then do some action.

I want to get that value in javascript.
The issue is that I don't want to use getComputedStyle as it will return the parsed value.

E.g,
I have a div, the div has a class.
In that class contains a custom property with some value, that value is, for example, `repeat(1, 1fr)`.

How can I know that value in Javascript?
`getComputedStyle` will return the parsed value E.g, `100px`

Code example:

```
<div class="test"></div>


body{
  --rows: repeat(2, 1fr)

  .test {
     grid-template-rows: var(--rows);
  }
}
```